# Ubuntu 20.04.3 how to change monitor ID numbers

Tags: multiple-monitors

I normally use a desktop with dual monitors, but it is down so I'm trying to use a Dell laptop with the docking station that has two DVI outputs. In Display settings it ID's the two external monitors as 2 and 3 and has a 1-Built-in that is off. How can I make the external monitors ID as 1 and 2 instead of 2 and 3? This seems to be find except when using multiple monitors with Virtual Box. It only gives the option of host monitor 1 and host monitor 2. I'm thinking it because they are seen as 2 and 3, because now I can't get this to work correctly. The laptop on the docking station has the lid closed.

[diplay settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvRNJ.jpg)

Edit: My goal is to be able to use multiple monitors with the laptop using external monitors. This is what I was using with the desktop before it died. Since I normally used the laptop as a standalone, maybe I'm missing something. But with this configuration, when I go to full screen on a guest, then click ctrl+home, go to View, then virtual screen 1 can got to host monitor 1 or 2 (the VB identifiers), but if I try to send virtual screen 2 to either what shows up as host monitor 1 or 2, then I get an icon for it on my left bar, but it can't be seen and then I can't do anything and the other screen never shows visible. When this happens I can't do anything on the guest and can't use the host fully except get to a terminal to kill the process.

I'm just guessing that this is because the host Ubuntu is seeing it as display 3 and not 1.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1382794/edit) your question and add more details like what is your goal here?  Do you want your VM in Virtualbox to open across multiple monitors?  Do you want your VM to open on a specific monitor?  Are you having a virtualbox refresh issue?  More details can help us help you!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. I'm not sure if my resolution was the best, but it's the only one that I could come up with so far. It turns out that the host machine (Ubuntu 20.04.3) was not the issue as I originally thought. I found that changing the guest machine from Wayland to Xorg resolved the issue.